# Find out the expiry date of cookie using javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I use functions for creating and reading cookies from quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html. I set also days to expire.
I would like to find out cookie's expiry date ... so I can tell visitor how many days he/she must wait until something is possible again == until cookie is automatically erased.

thanks thanks

Comment: Are you trying to use (client-side) cookies to prevent users from taking certain actions? They can always just delete the cookie, and then do the action again immediately if that's how you're preventing it.

Comment: well, of course I know, but this is how THEY ;) want it, so another user from the same PC can do these things as well.

Answer (score 5):

Hmm, there doesn’t seem to be an easy way to do this. JavaScript can only access the name/value pairs rather than the additional info that can be set in a cookie.

After some searching, the closest thing to a solution I could find (technically it is a workaround) is that if you really need to have the expiration date of a cookie, what you can do is to store it in *another cookie*. When you formulate the expiration date, set it as the expiration date of your target cookie, and the value of another cookie.

For example, set **NAME=BOB;expirationdate** and **NAME_EXP=expirateiondate;expirationdate**

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to get this information.

All you can access client-side is the `document.cookie` property, a single string composed of name-value pairs.  The other details are not accessible to the client.