# Read the expiration value of a cookie set by others

Tags: javascript, cookies

There is currently a chance for our customer's browser to have a particular cookie due to 
interactions with other related products in our company.

We wish to check for this cookie, and if present check it's expiration date and perform

some operations.

But is it possible to obtain the expiry date for a cookie from the browser via Javascript?

I can see that the expiry date is showing in browser via inspect (example Chrome) thus the information is there.

But can I capture it in Javascript?

Note that I am not the one setting this cookie, just checking for its existence and expiry.

If I were to perform the following command, I am able to see the required cookie listed in it. But it does not contain the expiry date.

```
document.cookie.split('; ').find(row => row.startsWith('theCookieName'))
```

Seen past related questions and all mentioned this is impossible pretty much.

Is there any work around for this in recent times or this is still the case?

Please advice. Thank you.

Example past queries.

[Find out the expiry date of cookie using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159731/find-out-the-expiry-date-of-cookie-using-javascript)

[Reading cookie expiration date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532193/reading-cookie-expiration-date)

Comment: I suggest to add the expiration date explicitly to the cookie data (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417087/jquery-cookie-expiration-value/15221924#15221924)
I assume that this should be possible due the fact the cookie is set by one of your company product(s)

Comment: @MartinGodzina This is not possible due to some restrictions and other usages.

Comment: What about CookieStore? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66621502/5273114

Comment: @MartinGodzina That would work but is limited to only Chrome and Edge unfortunately.